# how do you profile java source with intellij idea editor?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, profiler

I know that Netbeans has something of an "integrated" profiler, for instance you can run unit tests and use it to analyze and find what is slowing them down, where bottlenecks are.  Is it possible to profile code within IntelliJ IDEA editor?

Comment: As far as I know there is only one free profiler integration: [VisualVM](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=7115).

Comment: Apparently there's a non-free JProfiler plugin, FWIW http://stackoverflow.com/a/21156875/32453

Comment: Today I have installed the plugin VisualVM in INtellij IDEA ... initially I faced some issue but when I followed instructions provided in http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/05/setting-up-visualvm-in-under-5-minutes/  I could easily configure visualVM

Comment: Another question that's far too practical and useful to remain open.  SO should support questions with answer sets {N} where good enough  result(s) from set: [`X`, `Y`, `Z`] rise to the top via the community and the rest disappear/require extra action due to a natural falloff.  Again via the community.  "Do you really want to answer this?  Cause there's already an answer voted pretty dang good?"  "Yea, cause now there's a better best answer."  I mean that never happens in software right?

Comment: FYI: In IntelliJ IDEA v2018.3 Ultimate edition, the JVM Profiler is available as an experimental feature. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/09/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-git-submodules-jvm-profiler-macos-and-linux-and-more/

Comment: For Windows profiler, use 2019.2 RC: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/06/intellij-idea-2019-2-eap-4-profiling-tools-structural-search-preview-and-more/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can try the free VisualVM profiler integration via [a plug-in](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=7115).

Comment: Looks like if you buy IntelliJ "ultimate" it's said to include a built-in YourKit profiling agent, as well.  Not free, but included, so I guess related to my original question :)

Comment: No, YourKit agent will allow you to take CPU/Memory snapshot when contacting support with performance problems, it's not the profiler itself which will cost you additional $500+.

Comment: appears you're right thanks for the clarification.  YourKit is apparently only for profiling the IDE itself, not your own apps. Guess I'll just turn to Netbeans for now when I need to profile, and do the rest of my programming in IntelliJ :)

Comment: @rogerdpack why not just open VisualVM (you already have it installed through the jdk), select your app and press profile?

Comment: The problem with VisualVM launced by Krasa's VisualVM Launcher
plugin:
1) at the time it starts your test has finished.
2) on-fly profiling creates hot spots and hard to read CPU time stats.
There is a checkbox "edit configuration" in VisualVM but I don't see how to ask plugin to start test in right way
- wait until VisualVM starts and ready
- load test specific profiling config into VisualVM 
- run test code

Comment: YourKit version 2013 is not free but definetly claims functionality of stand alone java profiler with IDE Integration, IntelliJ IDEA 13 supported. Look at [**YourKit version 2013 release note.**](http://www.yourkit.com/changes/#cpu)

Comment: @smile-on Did you find a solution to the problem where your tests finish before VisualVM has launched? I am having the same problem myself.

Answer (score 27):

As pointed by Stephen Murby "the problem where your tests finish before VisualVM has launched".

Yes, this [VisualVMLauncher plug-in](https://github.com/krasa/VisualVMLauncher) does not put your test case on hold until VisualVM  has started. You may also need time to manually change profiling settings specific for the test. Solution is simple, your test case has to stop and wait until you manually tells it to continue. There are few ways of doing it:

1) put System.in.read(); as first line of test case and as VisualVM is ready press enter at console.

```
System.in.read();
```

2) If test case runner does not provide you with console, put wait until some magic file is created.

3) you can always play easy with sleep()

```
sleep(5 seconds);
```

This work around is not much of convenience but works for me as need to profile occasionally. The root cause of issue is in plug-in architecture of both IDEA and VisualVM are not thought to be collaborative. See [discussion with plug-in author](https://github.com/krasa/VisualVMLauncher/issues/10#issuecomment-32389688)
Hope that helps.