# Is there an IntelliJ Java Profiler

Tags: java, intellij-idea, profiler

Is there a Profiler for IntelliJ like the one for Matlab?

Let's say you have this code

```
a = true;
i = 0;
while(a)
{
   if(a)
      i++
   // some fancy stuff which takes 1 second each loop
   if(i > 1e6) break;
}
```

Now I run the code

In Matlab it would look like this after I opened the Profiler

```
calls  time
     1  0.0      a = true;
     1  0.0      i = 0;
     1  0.0      while(a)
                 {
   1e3  1.0        if(a)
   1e3  0.4         i++
   1e3  1e3         // some fancy stuff which takes 1 second each loop
   1e3  1.2         if(i > 1e3) break;
                 }
```

Comment: The NetBeans profiler could do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15976718/32453 may be related

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All profilers that are available for Java, which can be used in IntelliJ will show invocation times only aggregated on method level. You can use for example VisualVM, JProfiler or YourKit, but only summary time will be shown.

Comment: The NetBeans profiler (which is essentially what VisualVM is) can take times between any two lines in the code.

Comment: But it's not available in IntelliJ IDEA :)

Comment: I contradicted the part "*all profilers that are available for Java*".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right - it was a brachylogy

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thank you for pointing that out! I'll try it with NetBeans

Comment: Finally there is IntelliJ profiller: 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/09/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-git-submodules-jvm-profiler-macos-and-linux-and-more/

Pozdrawiam Kuba - dobre prezentacje.

Comment: @yami Thanks :)

Answer (score 18):

JProfiler has a [plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/253?pr=idea).

It adds "Profile" actions to IntelliJ IDEA, similar to the "Run" and "Debug" actions. The profiler UI is not embedded in IDEA but started as a separate process. However, you can use your existing run configurations for profiling and source code navigations goes back to IDEA.

You have to install [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) as a standalone product, the plugin will ask you about the installation directory of JProfiler when you profile something for the first time.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: quite expensive just for debugging

Comment: @GavriYashar but IntelliJ is already expensive, and JRebel is expensive too. If you don't want expensive then there's always NetBeans which has a FREE profiler ;)

Comment: @dexter meyers JProfiler: License with 1 year of Support & Upgrades €599 upgrade: For Single Licenses €159
IDEA: €179 upgrade €89.

for my purposes/uses JProfiler is too expensive. IDEA for me was not expensive if you don't want to use NetBeans or Eclipse. but i can stick with the fact that there is no such feature.

Comment: Finally there is IntelliJ profiller: 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/09/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-git-submodules-jvm-profiler-macos-and-linux-and-more/