# how to profile JUnit test run from Intellij Idea with VisualVM

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, profiling, visualvm

How to profile JUnit test run from Intellij Idea with VisualVM?  VisualVM  doesn't see any process? is it possible to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you profile java source with intellij idea editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976718/how-do-you-profile-java-source-with-intellij-idea-editor)

Answer (score 8):

There is a [plugin for JVisualVM](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3749-visualvm-profiler) mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976718/is-there-a-free-open-source-profiler-for-intellij-idea). With it, you can also run test cases.

Answer (score 3):

Note that recent IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate has integrated support for Java Flight Recorder and async-profiler which both are more precise than VisualVM:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cpu-profiler.html